# Angular - Array as Select Option Values

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this TypeScript:

```
public sendAlertDays: Array<any> = [
    { value: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], text: "all days" },
    { value: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], text: "monday-friday" },
    { value: [5, 6], text: "saturday-sunday" },
    { value: [0], text: "monday" },
    { value: [1], text: "tuesday" },
    { value: [2], text: "wednesday" },
    { value: [3], text: "thursday" },
    { value: [4], text: "friday" },
    { value: [5], text: "saturday" },
    { value: [6], text: "sunday" }
];

sendAlertDay: number[] = [0];
```

My Angular template do not pre-select 'monday' yet I have initialized well `sendAlertDay: number[] = [0]`

```html
<mat-select [(value)]="sendAlertDay" class="mat-primary">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let day of sendAlertDays" [value]="day.value">
        {{day.text}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Can you maybe share a stackblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `compareWith` property of the `mat-select`.

> @Input()
>   compareWith: (o1: any, o2: any) => boolean
>
> Function to compare the option values with the selected values. The first argument is a value from an option. The second is a value from the selection. A boolean should be returned.

Your component:

```js
public sendAlertDays: Array<any> = [
    { value: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], text: "all days" },
    { value: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], text: "monday-friday" },
    { value: [5, 6], text: "saturday-sunday" },
    { value: [0], text: "monday" },
    { value: [1], text: "tuesday" },
    { value: [2], text: "wednesday" },
    { value: [3], text: "thursday" },
    { value: [4], text: "friday" },
    { value: [5], text: "saturday" },
    { value: [6], text: "sunday" }
];

sendAlertDay: number[] = [0];

compareFN(optionValue: number[], selectionValue: number[]) {
    // compare two arrays
    return (
        optionValue.length === selectionValue.length &&
        optionValue.every((value, index) => value === selectionValue[index])
    );
}
```

Your template:

```html
 <mat-select [(value)]="sendAlertDay" [compareWith]="compareFN" class="mat-primary">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let day of sendAlertDays" [value]="day.value">
         {{day.text}}
     </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-mat-select-comparison) on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the selected value to be an array.

in order for this to work you need to set the value to be `string` instead of `number[]`

this for example would work :

```js
      public sendAlertDays: Array<any> = [
      { value: 'all', text: 'all days' },
      { value: 'monday-to-friday', text: 'monday-friday' },
      { value: 'saturday-sunday', text: 'saturday-sunday' },
      { value: 'monday', text: 'monday' },     
      { value: 'tuesday', text: 'tuesday' },
      { value: 'wednesday', text: 'wednesday' },
      { value: 'thursday', text: 'thursday' },
      { value: 'friday', text: 'friday' },
      { value: 'saturday', text: 'saturday' },
      { value: 'sunday', text: 'sunday' }];

      sendAlertDay: string = 'monday';
```

here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wzrmk-se36mv

an alternative would be to set the value to `number`, this would work as well